# Need help for \Composer\Installer::create & run

Tags: php, composer-php

I try to require new composer package by using PHP, and after a huge of research on Google I found that Composer have provide an official option [\Composer\Installer](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/1.5.3/Composer/Installer.html) and I started create a mini prototype.

`$installer->run()` return me `0` which mean success, but the outcome is not what I expected, I think I did something wrong.

```php
<?php
//...
$installer = Installer::create($io, $composer)
    ->setPreferDist()
    ->setSkipSuggest()
    ->setUpdate()
    ->setDumpAutoloader()
    ->setRunScripts(false)
    ->setOptimizeAutoloader(true);

try {
    $status = $installer->run();
} catch (\Throwable $exception) {
    $status = 1;
}
//...
```

This is my full PHP script:

```php
<?php
namespace mlaxwong\composer;

use Composer\Factory;
use Composer\Installer;
use Composer\Json\JsonFile;
use Composer\Json\JsonManipulator;
use Composer\IO\IOInterface;
use Composer\IO\NullIO;
use Composer\Package\Locker;

class Composer
{
    public function install(array $requirements, IOInterface $io = null) 
    {
        // try everything I can ..... ignore this 4 lines
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

        if ($io === null) $io = new NullIO;

        $jsonPath = dirname(__DIR__) . '/composer.json';
        $wd = dirname($jsonPath);

        // chdir($wd);

        $backup = file_get_contents($jsonPath);
        $config = $this->composerConfig($io, $jsonPath, true);
        $composer = Factory::create($io, $config);
        $lockFile = pathinfo($jsonPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'json'
            ? substr($jsonPath, 0, -4) . 'lock'
            : $jsonPath . '.lock';
        $rm = $composer->getRepositoryManager();
        $im = $composer->getInstallationManager();
        $locker = new Locker($io, new JsonFile($lockFile, null, $io), $rm, $im, file_get_contents($jsonPath));
        $composer->setLocker($locker);

        $success = true;
        $manipulator = new JsonManipulator(file_get_contents($jsonPath));

        $requireKey = 'require';
        $removeKey = 'require-dev';

        foreach ($requirements as $package => $constraint) 
        {
            if (
                !$manipulator->addLink($requireKey, $package, $constraint, true) ||
                !$manipulator->removeSubNode($removeKey, $package)
            ) {
                $success = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($success) file_put_contents($jsonPath, $manipulator->getContents());


        $installer = Installer::create($io, $composer)
            ->setPreferDist()
            ->setSkipSuggest()
            ->setUpdate()
            ->setDumpAutoloader()
            ->setRunScripts(false)
            ->setOptimizeAutoloader(true);

        try {
            $status = $installer->run();
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            $status = 1;
        }

        // chdir($wd);

        if ($status !== 0) 
        {
            file_put_contents($jsonPath, $backup);
            throw $exception ?? new \Exception('An error occurred');
        }
    }

    protected function composerConfig(IOInterface $io, string $jsonPath, bool $prepForUpdate = true): array
    {
        $file = new JsonFile($jsonPath, null, $io);
        $config = $file->read();
        return $config;
    }
}
```

and tested with:

```php
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use mlaxwong\composer\Composer;
$composer = new Composer;
$composer->install(['yiisoft/yii-core' => "*"]);
```

With the example code I was able to:

1. added "yiisoft/yii-core": "*" to **composer.json** "require" section
2. **composer.lock** modified (some of the existing package time change), but "yiisoft/yii-core" no added to **composer.lock**
3. "yiisoft/yii-core" package not added to **vendor** folder.

I had stuck on this 2 days ... I think I'm almost there, but there is really less document on Google.

I really need your help, sorry for my English and thanks for pending time to read my question.

Summary my objective:

1. Able to install new composer package by simple PHP API `$composer->install(["package-name", "version"]);`
2. Register package to composer.json and composer.lock, download package to vendor folder.
3. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to setup plugin store

Thanks again :)

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Why do you want to modify the existing `composer.json` and not just require the listed packed through your package's json file?

Comment: Why don't you just run `composer require yiisoft/yii-core` in command line?

Comment: Isn't `shell_exec("composer require xxx/xxx")` an option ?

Comment: @Paul ya I know what I do is what `require` does. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to setup a plugin store with UI friendly. Any way thanks for answering my question :)

Comment: @Eakethet thanks for reading my question :). Yup, but I future maybe I want do some custom action on package install.

Comment: @MlaxWong You can pack it up with plugin-package as pre-install, post-install scripts? https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events

Comment: @Eakethet ya composer had provided callback event for PHP, but ideally I want to using fully PHP to install package which provided by [composer official document](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/1.5.3/Composer/Installer.html). Really thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @NicoHaase ya what you say is what I'm trying to achieve, I had successfully modified `composer.json` file (able to add new package on require section), because of UI purpose, I hope PHP can done the `composer update` job for me. The reason I not using console command is because I found that composer had provide [this](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/1.5.3/Composer/Installer.html) official API to do this. again thanks for reply.

Comment: I don't know what kind of API that is, but if you want to install a dependency, go the regular way through adding it to your package's `composer.json`. Don't fiddle around with raw files

Comment: @NicoHaase similar [method](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/services/Composer.php#L152) used by [CraftCMS](https://craftcms.com)

Comment: Only because any other system uses it, that does not sound like a good approach. Still, you have not told why you want to go this more error prone way

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm nobody, I learn from example. I did `composer update` and `install` all the time. I just want try to use some proper way which somebody done well. I already told you because of UI purpose, user friendly mostly means no developer friendly. My question was already very clear ... I half way done `Installer::create` and `$installer->run()` ... sure I know `shell_exec("composer require xxx/xxx")` able to do this, but that maybe is my last option ... again thanks for reply

Comment: One point to find a solution could be to call `setVerbose` and see whether it outputs anything unusual

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks I will look on `setVerbose`